# How to repeate mysql cursor with parameter?

Tags: mysql, cursor

I have following cursor with parameter. Now I need to set parameter during loop. Is their a short way to do this?

*Cursor:*

```
DECLARE curs1 CURSOR FOR 
     SELECT  USER_ID,affiliate_id
 FROM `wpmr_aff_referrals` WHERE affiliate_id=AFFILIATEID;
```

*Cursor body part:*

```
OPEN curs1;    
read_loop : LOOP    
FETCH curs1 INTO USERID,AFFILIATEID;
IF (vCNT>=3) THEN  
set AFFILIATEID=10;
ELSE
set new.affiliate_id= 5;
END IF;    
END LOOP read_loop;
CLOSE curs1;
```

At `set AFFILIATEID=10;` it should be re-opened like in Oracle we do open cursor as `c_emp (23);`

Comment: What do you mean with "reopened"? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I mean cursor should be called again with new value `AFFILIATEID`

Comment: But what do you want to achieve? Maybe you don't need a cursor at all?

Comment: I need to get query result based upon `affiliate_id` and this will change during loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this with inner block and loop.

```
    OPEN curs1;    
        read_loop : LOOP    
        FETCH curs1 INTO USERID,AFFILIATEID;
        IF (vCNT>=3) THEN  
        set AFFILIATEID=10;
        ELSE
        set new.affiliate_id= 5;
        END IF;    

        BLOCK2: begin
                     DECLARE USERID1 varchar(50);
     DECLARE AFFILIATEID1 varchar(50) default
                    declare curs2 cursor for
                       SELECT  USER_ID,affiliate_id
         FROM `wpmr_aff_referrals` WHERE affiliate_id=AFFILIATEID;

                    open curs2;
                    LOOP2: loop
                        FETCH curs2 INTO USERID1,AFFILIATEID1;

                    end loop LOOP2;
                    CLOSE curs2;
                end BLOCK2;


        END LOOP read_loop;
        CLOSE curs1;
```